# Java Random Generator's seed producing different outputs

Tags: java, random, numbers, generator, seed

While trying to create a Coin object class using two specific seeds passed into the object upon creation, I have noticed that when passing in the seed to an int "seed", the seed variable produces a different variable than just inputting the specific number into the random number generator. Here's some code from the Coin class:

```
public int headCount;
public int tailCount;
public int seed;

public Coin( int n ){
    seed = n;
    headCount = 0;
    tailCount = 0;
}
public Random flipGenerator = new Random(seed); 

public String flip(){
    String heads = "H";
    String tails = "T";

    boolean nextFlip = flipGenerator.nextBoolean();
    if (nextFlip == true)
    {
        headCount++;
        return heads;
    }
    if (nextFlip == false)
    {
        tailCount++;
        return tails;
    }
    return null;
}
```

Here's from the file that creates and prints the Coin objects:

```
Coin coin1 = new Coin( 17 );
Coin coin2 = new Coin( 13 );
```

The code in that file prints out the outcome of the random flips 20 times using the 17 seed, 10 times with the 13 seed and finally 35 times with the 17 seed again. However the output is incorrect when using

```
public Random flipGenerator = new Random(seed);
```

as opposed to

```
public Random flipGenerator = new Random(17);
```

or

```
public Random flipGenerator = new Random(13);
```

Why is this happening?

Comment: What constitutes "incorrect"? However, have you tried running in a debugger and looking at the initialization of the variables? What happens if you were to move the flipGenerator into the constructor?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instance fields are initialized before the constructor is called.

In terms of execution order, this code:

```
public int headCount;
public int tailCount;
public int seed;

public Coin( int n ){
    seed = n;
    headCount = 0;
    tailCount = 0;
}
public Random flipGenerator = new Random(seed);
```

is functionally equivalent to this:

```
public int headCount;
public int tailCount;
public int seed;
public Random flipGenerator = new Random(seed); 

public Coin( int n ){
    seed = n;
    headCount = 0;
    tailCount = 0;
}
```

In Java, any fields which were not explicitly initialized are given a value of zero/null/false, so you are *always* doing `flipGenerator = new Random(0)`.  By the time you initialize `seed` in your constructor, the Random object has already been created.  The fact that the instance field was declared after the constructor is irrelevant, because all instance fields and their initialization expressions are executed before a constructor is invoked.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you initialize the `Coin` class it will use 0 as the seed. Regardless if you put the `flipGenerator` initialization below the constructor, it will still get called in the constructor since it is an instance variable.

```
Coin coin1 = new Coin( 17 );
Coin coin2 = new Coin( 13 );
```

This code is using 0 because, by the time you pass the seed, the flipGenerator was initialized with the default seed of 0.

You need to do this

```
    public int headCount;
    public int tailCount;
    public int seed;
    public Random flipGenerator;

    public Coin( int n ){
        seed = n;
        headCount = 0;
        tailCount = 0;
        flipGenerator = new Random(seed);
    }
  ...
}
```